# How to align icon on both side of text in html buttons

Tags: html, css

Guys I am using a button with icon on 2 side of the text and it works when the text is smaller, but at times I have longer text and had to break them into 2 lines. how to do it ?

```
<button type="submit"  class="button-orange width-280" > <img src="img/icon-getDetails.png"> Get More Details <img class="button-icon" src="img/icon-external-link.png">   </button>
<button type="submit"  class="button-orange width-280" > <img src="img/icon-basket.png"> Add to compare basket <span class="badge white">3</span> <img class="button-icon-chevron" src="img/icon-chevron-right.png">   </button>
```

I am attaching the image with this. I need the longer text also to be appearing like the 1st button.

[image]

Comment: create a fiddle will be better..

Answer (score 0):

You could set the icon as a background image on the button, and pad the button's sides to the width of the icons. Please note this method is [not IE8 friendly](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds). :(

*For example*

HTML:

```
<button>
  Get more details
</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  background:
    url('img/icon-getDetails.png') top left no-repeat,
    url('img/icon-external-link.png') top right no-repeat;

  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6srbqgwf/) that might help you imagine it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your CSS, but I'm guessing that the class `width-280` adds a `width: 280px` to the button.

Instead of using a fixed width, use a minimum width. Change `width: 280px` to `min-width: 280px`.